# Program for simplifying expressions of many body pauli operators

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

I've come across [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/488145/program-for-simplifying-expressions-of-many-body-pauli-operators), which was never ported over to Computational Science, so I'm hoping for an answer here. The question is how to simplify expressions involving products and commutators of these matrices, i.e.
[image: ![enter image description here]

Using SymPy, I can make some progress, such as

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.paulialgebra import Pauli, evaluate_pauli_product
from sympy import I
from sympy.physics.quantum import TensorProduct as tp
from sympy.physics.quantum import Commutator as cm
from sympy.physics.quantum import tensor_product_simp as tpsimp
Id = 1
X = Pauli(1)
Y = Pauli(2)
Z = Pauli(3)
term1 = tp(X,Y)
term2 = tp(Id,cm(Y,X).doit())
result = tpsimp(cm(term1,term2).doit())
print(evaluate_pauli_product(result))
```

but the output, `2*I*(1xsigma3*sigma1xsigma2 - sigma1xsigma2*1xsigma3)`, is far from simplified. Is there anything better that can be done? I don't know how to specify which index the tensor product should consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantum expressions often need the help of `qapply`:

```
In [7]: from sympy.physics.quantum import qapply

In [8]: e = evaluate_pauli_product(result)

In [9]: e
Out[9]: 2⋅ⅈ⋅(1⨂ σ₃⋅σ₁⨂ σ₂ - σ₁⨂ σ₂⋅1⨂ σ₃)

In [10]: qapply(e)
Out[10]: 2⋅ⅈ⋅1⨂ σ₃⋅σ₁⨂ σ₂ - 2⋅ⅈ⋅σ₁⨂ σ₂⋅1⨂ σ₃

In [11]: tpsimp(qapply(e))
Out[11]: 4⋅σ₁⨂ σ₁
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/quantum/qapply.html

On the other hand that output doesn't look exactly like what you apparently expected. Personally I don't know enough about QM to say if it's correct or not.

Comment: indeed, the screenshot I lifted was a typo, thanks!

Comment: this does not work if you extend it to 3 tensor products. Is there any way to make this more reliable?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know. There are probably ways but it also probably deserves a new question with new code to demonstrate the problem.